# Проблема с редиректом

Tags: php, redirect

Подскажите, как можно отследить редирект?
Я тестил сайт ([линк](http://csgo-forecast.com/)) в w3c валидаторе и в гуглосервисах, говорит что много редиректов и не хочет выдавать результат.
Так же ставил расширение для хрома, тоже говорит что нужно упростить редиректы. Как их отследить? Есть такая возможность? (кроме копания кода, просто можно перед каждым header сделать запись url в файл)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С редиректами у вас там действительно что-то не то. Если с корня на английскую версию мы прыгаем за один 302, то с русской - непонятно. Тревожным сигналом служит уже то, что при **явном** указании русской версии всё равно перекидывает на английскую. Видимо, движок считает себя умней всех, игнорирует явное указание языка, начинает проявлять свой непомерный ум (анализировать куки, юзер-агента, HTTP-заголовки, выставлять  новые куки, которые потом сам же при каких-то условиях не ловит и тд). В результате всё заканчивается бесконечными редиректами.

Так что без копания в коде вам не обойтись. URL протоколировать бессмысленно. А вот поковыряться по условиям, по которым он принимает решение о редиректе, нужно. Заодно может и найдёте где ему надавать по рукам, чтобы не слишком умничал (я имею в виду что если явно указано `/en` или `/ru` он вообще не должен больше никуда рыпаться).

P.S. После первого коммента. Валидаторы всё так же матерятся, редирект с русской версии поправился наполовину: он всё равно есть, но уже не на английскую, а на тот же адрес! Видимо, где-то что-то глючит при обработке не "настоящих" браузеров, а роботов типа того же `wget` или робота валидатора, которые не отдают какие-то ожидаемые движком заголовки:

```
[00:08:45] tmp $ wget -S http://csgo-forecast.com/ru
--2015-05-19 00:29:13--  http://csgo-forecast.com/ru
Распознаётся csgo-forecast.com (csgo-forecast.com)… 91.122.62.102
Подключение к csgo-forecast.com (csgo-forecast.com)|91.122.62.102|:80... соединение установлено.
HTTP-запрос отправлен. Ожидание ответа... 
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Date: Mon, 18 May 2015 21:29:11 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Win64) PHP/5.5.6
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.6
  Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=93mmb1kqn6d9fuum8kuk95nbb3; path=/
  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
  Pragma: no-cache
  Location: http://csgo-forecast.com/ru
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Адрес: http://csgo-forecast.com/ru [переход]
--2015-05-19 00:29:14--  http://csgo-forecast.com/ru
Повторное использование соединения с csgo-forecast.com:80.
HTTP-запрос отправлен. Ожидание ответа... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Mon, 18 May 2015 21:29:13 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Win64) PHP/5.5.6
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.6
  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
  Pragma: no-cache
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Длина: нет данных [text/html]
```

Comment: А сейчас вы можете у себя проверить? Уже нормально?

Comment: См. обновление.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас еще копну